# Link not taking up full div

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

I have a linkbutton that should show:
Register                        >

I tried to solve this by putting 2 divs floated into a parent div.  Adding 2 linkbuttons inside one with Register as text and one with > as text.

I then added a css class to have the a tag take up the full div.  For the register part this works perfectly, for the > part this does not work at all.
Any suggestions?

Tried to replace > with text to see what that does, but also no solution there, the > character doesn't seem to be the problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />

.eventWebsite {
  /*padding:10px 10px;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffc903;
  align-items: center;
}

.eventWebsite a {
  color: inherit;
}

.eventArrow {
  color: #000;
}

.link_class2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 6% 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row noMargin col-12 pl0 pr0 eventWebsite">
  <div class="col-10 pl0">
    <a id="cntModal_hypEventWebsite" class="link_class2" href="https://www.eventbrite.co.uk/e/new-crestron-cpd-transforming-design-with-light-tickets-55068781207">Event website</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 EventArrow" style="text-align:right;">
    <a id="cntModal_hypEventWebsiteArrow" class="link_class2" href="https://www.eventbrite.co.uk/e/new-crestron-cpd-transforming-design-with-light-tickets-55068781207">&gt;</a>
  </div>
  <br style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Looks like you have some essential CSS missing....you might want to add that.

Comment: Based on your div element, you appear to have a front end framework your attempting to use.  That would be helpful, since that framework will define your grid structure and how inputs are handled.

Comment: just regular bootstrap, i have added the link I am using